# Не работает простой код jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть видео, где этот же код нормально рабоатет, а у меня нет. В чем баг?

```html
<img src='1.ipg' alt='Малюки' title='Малюнки'><br>
<img src='2.ipg'><br>
<img src='3.ipg'><br>
<img src='4.ipg' alt='Малюнки' title='Малюнки'><br>
```

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(':not(img)[alt])').attr('alt', 'jQuery');
</script>
```

Comment: у вас нет в разметке элементов не картинок у которых есть атрибут `alt`

Comment: Может jQuery не подключена?

Comment: нет подключена.
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exeiFKa9mjw&index=11&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXQk_TTlSO7y7J1l5e-RMgi
вот здесь на 4 мин все норм работает

Comment: @Grundy, как-то стыдно давать ответ на этот вопрос даже. `$(document).ready(function() {...}` не прописан, `jquery` не подключен

Comment: @Doofy, а вот и нет

Comment: Да госпади, да опечатка у вас. Должно быть `$(':not(img[alt])')` Т.е. после `img` скобочка закрывающаяся лишняя... Между прочим, взглянув в консоль можно было спокойно это увидеть - там ошибка это вывалилась бы в виде `Syntax error`

Comment: @Grundy эх вы, профессионал сайта, а не увидели опечатку. Стыдно, товарищ!)

Comment: спасибо!! не мог заметить

Comment: @yethyd держите консоль всегда открытой, и в любой непонятной ситуации всегда в первую очередь смотрите в неё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, В любой непонятной ситуации смотри в консолечку. © АлексейШиманский

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, я ответ писал хороший с разбором того, что не так, а на видео вообще дрянь указана, похоже записывальщик не счел нужным сказать что этот атрибут при таком селекторе не только к нужным img добавится.

Comment: @Grundy то, что добавит всем остальным - это да)) но код то рабочий)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну это как сказать :-) он не выдает ошибок в консоль, да :-) но делает не то, что ожидалось :-)

Answer (score 3):

Стоит разобрать какие элементы выбирает данный селектор, и какие элементы должны быть выбраны.

Разберем селектор

```
:not(img)[alt]
```

Он состоит из двух частей

1. селектор [*:not*](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) - выбирает все элементы ***не*** удовлетворяющие селектору, в данном случае: `:not(img)` выберет **все** элементы **не** `img`
2. [селектор по атрибуту](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) - выбирает **все** элементы у которых **есть** указанный атрибут, в данном случае: `[alt]` выберет **все** элементы у которых присутствует атрибут `alt`

Вместе эти селекторы вернут: **все** элементы  **не** `img`, у которых есть атрибут `alt`

Судя по предоставленной разметке, ожидалась выборка **всех** элементов `img` **без** атрибута `alt`, это соответствует следующему селектору:

```
img:not([alt])
```

```js
$('img:not([alt])').attr('alt', 'jQuery');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='1.ipg' alt='Малюки' title='Малюнки'><br>
<img src='2.ipg'><br>
<img src='3.ipg'><br>
<img src='4.ipg' alt='Малюнки' title='Малюнки'><br>
```

<sub>не смотрите то видео, на нем кроме картинкам атрибут альт также добавился тегам html,head,body и всем остальным</sub>

Comment: Ништяковый ответ, плюсю

Answer (score -3):

Возможно, вы забыли поставить событие, при котором этот скрипт должен отрабатывать?

например

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
     $( document ).ready(function() {
               $(":not(img)[alt])").attr ("alt", "jQuery");   
     }); 
</script>
```

Или вы применяете код к странице, где нет подходящих элементов

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exeiFKa9mjw&index=11&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXQk_TTlSO7y7J1l5e-RMgi
4-та минута